# Replace words from one vector of strings with blanks if they match in another vector of strings

Tags: r

I am trying to find any matching of "City" inside "Cust.Name". If there is a match, replace the presence of "City" with a blank in "Cust.Name". Therefore only "Cust.Name" without "City" will show up.

```
Cust.Name <- as.data.frame(c("Eric Lee", "Mendham Middle School", "John Doe", "Johnson Elementary"))
colnames(Cust.Name) <- "Cust.Name"

City <- as.data.frame(c("Durham", "Mendham", "Elon", "Johnson"))
colnames(City) <- "City"

Customer = cbind(Cust.Name , City)
Customer$Cust.Name = as.character(Customer$Cust.Name)
Customer$City = as.character(Customer$City)
```

I have tried this:

```
Customer$Cust.Name = sapply(gsub(pattern = Customer$City , replacement = '' , x = Customer$Cust.Name), function(x) x )
```

Desired results should be:

```
"Eric Lee" , "Middle School" , "John Doe" , "Elementary"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

cust_name <- c("Eric Lee", "Mendham Middle School", "John Doe", "Johnson Elementary")
city <- c("Durham", "Mendham", "Elon", "Johnson")

str_replace_all(cust_name, city, "") %>% str_squish()
# [1] "Eric Lee"      "Middle School" "John Doe"      "Elementary"
```

Noting above only works if the vectors operate in "pairs" -- otherwise, you will want to `paste(..., collapse = "|")` the city. For example:

```
# Note the new order of `cust_name`
cust_name <- c("Eric Lee", "John Doe", "Mendham Middle School", "Johnson Elementary")
city <- c("Durham", "Mendham", "Elon", "Johnson")

str_replace_all(cust_name, paste(city, collapse = "|"), "") %>%
  str_squish()
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, yes I needed them to be pairs in this case. This solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub`, i.e.

```
gsub(paste(City$City, collapse = '|'), '', Cust.Name$Cust.Name)
#[1] "Eric Lee"       " Middle School" "John Doe"       " Elementary"
```

Comment: I needed the strings to be in pairs for this case.

Comment: what do you mean? I get your expected output